# Array in database error

Tags: php, arrays, post, mysqli

I've got an array of usernames that needs to be matched with a db table upon post.

When I post it, I get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /hermes/waloraweb008/b2049/information/folder/page.php on line 43 post_ok|213

This creates the array after the `@`sign (Works fine.):

```
$data = preg_replace('!((@)([-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+))!i', '<a href="user.php?u=$3">$1</a>', $data);
$mentions = preg_match_all('!((@)([-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+))!i', $data, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $findnames)
    {
        $shiz = implode(',',$findnames);
    }
```

This is what I want to check for the array within the db.

```
$mentionsql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN '$shiz'";
$mentionquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $mentionsql);
$row83 = mysqli_fetch_row($mentionquery);
$musername = $row83["username"];
```

So that I can later do this:

```
mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO notifications(username, initiator, app, which_status,did_read, date_time) 
                        VALUES('$musername','$log_username','<a href=user.php?u=$log_username>$log_username</a> mentioned you in a status.','$statusid',now(),now())");
```

Any ideas as to why there is an error?

Comment: Echo out your SQL statement, and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can interpret your code `$shiz` is a comma-separated string of usernames, so: `$shiz == 'user1, user2, user3'`

on this line you are generating your query:

```
$mentionsql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN '$shiz'";
```

if you insert my example of `$shiz` you get a query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN 'user1, user2, user3'"
```

However, the actual syntax for the SQL command [`In`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) requires round brackets. Furthermore, if the usernames are strings, you need to put them in single quotes. So your query should look like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')"
```

Comment: Aaaaah I see. I'll get to work on that. Any idea on how to make that happen?

Comment: First, you need to replace the single-quotes in `$mentionsql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN '$shiz'";` with round brackets. Second, if your usernames are not escaped with single-quotes, you could change your `implode` call to `$shiz = "'".implode("','",$findnames)."'"`. My PHP skills are a bit rusty so I'm unsure if the syntax is correct, but the general idea should work.